# CSS3 pulsing circle Firefox issue

Tags: firefox, css

I have a CSS3 pulsing circle (animating scale to 1.1). I have applied a tiny roation to fix the jumpy Firefox animation issue.

```
animation: button_pulse 2s infinite ease-out;

transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
```

However on Firefox there is still a slight issue on the right hand side with what I can only describe as a white lip. Any ideas on how to get the entire circle to stay smooth.

It looks great in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/alexcroox/9JpHT/

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried this on a Firefox 16, and it does work for me. The only thing I can see on the right is not white and looks rather like an anti aliasing problem. Is it what you're talking about ?
`EDIT` : i've been experiencing differences about how browsers render text in a <canvas>. What you see here is probably due to how Firefox renders curves and i don't think there is something you can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an inner shadow to remove the white lip, the area still looks a bit square in FF but it's better than it was.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```